# How to add single quotes to the parameter

Tags: sql-server, string

I have to store data in table by appending the single quotes in the parameter i am receiving. Suppose i have parameter **@parameter** ,so i want to store it as **'@parameter'** in the table.How to implement this?

Comment: what did you try ? and did you search this kind of question in #SO ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server you double-up single quotes inside a string literal, so you'd need something like:

```
'''' + @parameter + ''''
```